# In Cocoa, what is the difference between a View and a Frame?

Tags: macos, cocoa, view, frame

I have searched online and read through Apple docs, but I can't find a straightforward explanation of the difference between a View and a Frame, and how they relate to one another. I would appreciate an explanation, and please feel free to include any other related terms that will help clarify.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A "view" is a visual element that appears in your app's UI. Most of the elements you see on screen (labels, buttons, etc.) are types of "views". See [What Are Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/WhatAreViews/WhatAreViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH5-SW1).

In Cocoa, the `frame` is merely a property of a view that defines where the view is located (the `origin`, defined as the `x` and `y` coordinates that dictate where the view is placed within its superview) and how big it is (the `size`, defined as the `width` and `height` of the view). See [Understanding a View's Frame and Bounds](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Coordinates/Coordinates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH10-SW9).

Comment: Could not be explained better!